# Pagination - number of pages

Tags: php, html, database, pagination

This is my pagination:

```
if (isset(filter_input_array(INPUT_GET)["page"])) {
    $page= filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
} else {
    $page= 1;
}

$request= "";

if (filter_input_array(INPUT_POST)) {
    $request= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'request', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
} else if (isset(filter_input_array(INPUT_GET)["request"])) {
    $request= filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'request', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
```

Database:

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT " . (($page* 50) - 50) . ",50");
```

index.php

```
<nav role="navigation">
   <ul class="cd-pagination custom-buttons">
       <li class="arrows"><a href="index.php?page=<?php
         if ($page > 1) {
           $prev= $page - 1;
           echo escape($prev);
         } else {
           echo 1;
         }?>&request=<?php echo escape($request) ?>">Prev</a></li>

         <li class="arrows">
         <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo escape(++$page); ?>&request=
         <?php echo escape($request) ?>">Next</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

It works fine like this, but I would like it show number of pages not just prev/next. I looked for soulution on internet but nothing worked...

Comment: You need to make another query without the "LIMIT" clause and calculate the total of page from the total of returned rows

Answer (score 0):

Query without `LIMIT`:

`SELECT * FROM users;`

Get the number of rows from this query. I can't see your DB class so don't know what implementation you are using. Check out the documentation for [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Then you need to do: `ceil($numRows / $numberOfResultsPerPage);` to get the number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET["p"])) { 
    $p = $_GET["p"]; 
} else { 
    $p = 1; 
}

$per_page = 50
$from = ($p-1) * $per_page; 


$sql = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM users LIMIT $from,$per_page");
```

Then with the total you can use the ceil function to get the number of pages

```
$total_pages = ceil($total / $per_page);
```

In the end forech on $total_pages to display each page as `<a href="?p=$i"></a>` element.

Hope it help !

Comment: Did you retrieve the total from your sql query ?

Comment: @Tov > You need to store the result of your query in the $total variable